# How to groupBy two field in dataweave 2.0?

Tags: dataweave, mule4

I'm looking for an output similar to this one below where i want to groupBy costomer and orderid.

Input:

```json
[
    {
        "item": 621,
        "orderid": "ON22",
        "qty": 45.0,
        "customer": "813",
        "date": "1988-08-13"
    },
  {
        "item": 63,
        "orderid": "ON22",
        "qty": 7,
        "customer": "813",
        "date": "2001-08-13"
    },
 {
        "item": 54,
        "orderid": "AD546",
        "qty": 9,
        "customer": "813",
        "date": "2014-08-13"
    },
   {
        "item": 611,
        "orderid": "ON222723-JH",
        "qty": 78.0,
        "customer": "890",
        "date": "1990-05-11"
    }
]
```

Desired output:

```json
[
   {
      "customer":"890",
       "orderid":"ON222723-JH",
      "data":[
         {
            "item":611,
            "qty":78.0,
            "date":"1990-05-11"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "customer":"813",
        "orderid":"ON22",
      "data":[
         {
            "item":621,
            "qty":45.0,
            "date":"1988-08-13"
         },
       {
       "item": 63,
        "qty": 7,
        "date": "2001-08-13"
      }
      ]
   },
   {
      "customer":"813",
       "orderid":"AD546",
      "data":[
         {
         "item": 54,
        "qty": 9,
        "date": "2014-08-13"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually use the trick of concating the keys I need in `groupBy` to achieve what you need.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json

// Concat customer and ordered as the key to group the items. Use a character that can't be part of any of the fields.
var groupedOrders = payload groupBy ((item, index) -> item.customer ++ "|" ++ item.orderid)
---
valuesOf(groupedOrders) map ((items, index) -> 
    {
        // I'm getting the first element as all in the items collection should have the same customer and orderid
        "customer": items[0].customer, 
        "orderid": items[0].orderid, 
        // The map here is just to remove the repeated fields
        "data": items map ((item, index) -> item - "customer" - "orderid")
    }
)
```

Comment: Just to be consistent with the output, you would want to add orderBy (-$.customer) before the groupBy.